# Browser Mode and Document Mode in IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, html

In IE9 Browser, a page is not displayed properly. Using developer toolbar I have found the following screenshot in which it displays

```
Browser Mode:IE9 Compat View
Document Mode : IE7 standards
```

If I force the browser to

```
Browser Mode : IE9 
DOucment Mode : IE9 Standard
```

Then it display properly.

How can I show the page properly without forcing the browser to IE9 mode.

[image: Browser Mode Document Mode]

Comment: Your problem is that whatever markup/CSS/JS you have doesn't work in IE7.  Fix that, and all will be good in the world.  We can be more helpful if you share your markup/CSS/JS.

Comment: @AymanSafadi, thank you so much. I have used html5 markup and the address is http://nazmulweb.com

Comment: [Defining Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah... Internet Explorer didn't support HTML5 until IE9.  Add this to the header:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Also, add an HTML5 reset style sheet like this one:
http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

Comment: Though I was browsing in IE9, I had the above problem.

Comment: What is the problem anyways? It looks like there's something wrong with it on IE7, but it looks fine on IE9.  The problems in IE7 are definitely HTML5-related.  IE7 doesn't know how to interpret the "<section>" tag.

Comment: What does html5.js do? I have seen inside the html5.js and it seems all lines are commented.

Comment: This script is originally from: http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/ According to the author, "It's conditional within the code, so Firefox et al won't run the code - but it doesn't hurt to wrap it in an IE conditional call to reduce the http pulls for other browsers"

Answer (score 0):

It looks different in the emulated version of IE7 because you wrote it in HTML5, and IE7 was developed before HTML5 was even an apple in the eye of the W3C.

Be careful using hacks such as the one prescribed in the answer above. It is better to understand each bit of code you add to your site.

It is also important to remember that every additional document, hell every keystroke you add, creates a greater load on the server and browser, which increases your load time.